# Replace month abbreviation with numbers

Tags: r, date

I have the following sample dataset

```r
Date = c("12Oct2020","13Oct2020","14Oct2020")
```

I understand that I am able to use the following codes to transform the abbreviations into numeric but for my case the month is sandwiched between the day and year.

```r
tst <- c("Jan","Mar","Dec")
match(tst,month.abb)
```

So how do I transform my dataset into

```
"12/10/2020", "13/10/2020", "14/10/2020"
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
Date = c("12Oct2020","13Oct2020","14Oct2020")
format(strptime(Date, format="%d%b%Y"), format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

The inner part (`strptime()`) converts from your particular date format to a `Date` object: the outer part (`format()`) prints your date in the requested output format.

Note that this will only work if your computer/R session is using an English *locale*, because the `%b` format specifier looks for the abbreviated month name *in the current locale*. In French it would still be OK, but in a German locale [it would be looking for "Okt" instead](https://web.library.yale.edu/cataloging/months) ...

Comment: Fantastic, just what I needed. Thanks a lot pal!